# What are the Swift frameworks available?

Tags: swift

From doing a bit of iOS development I found that some things had to be done in C. For example the address book API was not available at the time in Objective-C.

Now that Swift is out, what frameworks have been ported to it? I can't seem to be able to find a list. I am aware that you can call an Objective-C method from Swift but I don't think you can call a C one from Swift.
Is Apple planning to port the C only frameworks to Swift or at least Objective-C? I don't particularly like the idea of having a project sprinkled with three different languages as it makes it hard to find people to maintain it.

Edit: Changed C++ to C

Comment: does Apple have any C++ only framework?

Comment: ABAddressBook uses a plain C interface (based on CoreFoundation) and is available in Swift. A starting point for all iOS frameworks is https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/navigation/#section=Frameworks. Which framework do you use that is *not* available in Swift?

Comment: The entire Foundation framework is available in Swift. 3rd party frameworks can be imported through a bridging header.

Comment: You may wish to give a concrete example of a problem you're having using a particular framework from Swift.

Comment: @MartinR, when I did iOS work and the client wanted address book work I found myself facing documentation in C which I didn't fully understand. Swift feels very natural to me but haven't had a chance to work with it and my first thought was "I hope they ported the address book API to Swift so that I will be able to make sense of it". Using the link you posted I noticed that reference pages now have an option on top to show the Swift API which is what my question was about. If you copy your comment as an answer I will be able to close this question and accept your answer. Thanks!

Comment: Wait... things were done in C++, not C?  The Objective-C is only a different implementation of C++ to solve a problem with C (the lacking of objects).  I would find it peculiar that something in iOS  was written in C++ as opposed to C/Objective-C.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [iOS Developer Library](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/navigation/#section=Frameworks)
is a good starting point for documentation of all iOS frameworks, e.g. the
[ABAddressBook Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AddressBook/Reference/ABAddressBookRef_iPhoneOS/index.html).

Apple has updated the framework documentation to show both the (Objective-)C and the
Swift interface, where available:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The question is bogus because its premise is false. There's no problem using the address book framework in Swift. It's a pain in the butt because of memory management issues, but it's perfectly doable. For examples, see https://github.com/mattneub/Programming-iOS-Book-Examples/blob/master/bk2ch18p713addressBook/ch31p973addressBook/ViewController.swift

I've rewritten all my code in Swift, and on the whole there was nothing I couldn't do natively, except for a couple of very small moves such as designating a property `@dynamic` in the Objective-C sense, or defining and passing a pointer to a C function, which both require use of Objective-C.

Your not understanding the C documentation should not be confused with the framework needing to be "ported". It doesn't need to be "ported". Nothing needs to be "ported". The whole point of Swift is that it interfaces with the APIs as they stand.

Answer (score 1):

> For example the address book API was not available at the time in
>   Objective-C.

Objective-C is a superset of C, which means that any API that is available in C is available in Objective-C.

You just mean there was no class-based API.

> Now that Swift is out, what frameworks have been ported to it?

All Cocoa frameworks can be imported directly in Swift. Plus any custom C or Objective-C APIs can be used in Swift if you put it in the bridging header. That doesn't mean those APIs have been "ported to Swift"; rather, Swift can import C and Objective-C APIs.

Comment: This is a great explanation. Thanks for clearing it up.